# Check if variable is isset whilst creating new variable

Tags: php, if-statement, concatenation, isset

I am attempting to create a dynamic description where the test changes as to what the product characteristics, I have created all separate chunks of text that are set if the product has that feature/characteristic, now I am compiling all the text together for the final description however I need to check if each variable isset whilst creating the variable.

Please see what I am attempting below:

```
$description = isset($desc1)? echo $desc1 :'' . isset($desc2)? echo $desc2 :';
```

There will be around 20 different variables which I need to check if they are isset so separate if statements with each different combination of text is not an option. I have done much research and cannot find the solution to this

thank you for any help

EDIT:

How the variables are set:

```
$desc1 = "Released " . $model['month'] . " " . $model['year'] . "," . " ". "the" . " " . $brand['brand'] . " " . $model['model'] . " " . "is an";
if ($model['interchangeable'] == 1) { 
    $desc2 = "interchangeable lens" . " " . substr($category_name['category'], 0, -1) . " "; 
} elseif ($model['interchangeable'] == 0) { 
    $desc2 = "fixed lens" . " " . substr($category_name['category'], 0, -1) . " "; 
}
$desc3 = "that scores";
if ($score[0] >= 70) { $desc4 = "highly"; } elseif ($score[0] >= 40) { $desc4 = "moderately"; } elseif ($score[0] < 40) { $desc4 = "poorly"; } 
$desc5 = "at" . " " . $score[0] . "/100" . " " . "in comparison with other cameras."; 
$desc6= "Some stand out features is the" . " " . $model['mp'] . " " .  "sensor"; 


if (strpos($res, "-") !== FALSE) { } else { 
    $desc7 = "capable of recording at" . " " . $model['res'] . " " . "resolution" . " "; 
}
$desc8 = "also";
if ($model['interchangeable'] == 1) { 

    if (strpos($model['focus_points'], "-") !== FALSE) { } else { 
        $desc9x1 = "-" . " " . $model['focus_points'] . " " . "Points" . " ";
    }
    if (strpos($model['frame_rate'], "-") !== FALSE) { } else { 
        $desc9x2 = "-" . " " . $model['frame_rate'] . " " . "Burst Rate" . " ";
    }
    if (strpos($model['sensor_size'], "-") !== FALSE) { } else { 
        $desc9x3 = "-" . " " . $model['sensor_size'] . " " . "Sensor" . " ";
    }
    if (strpos($model['viewfinder'], "None") !== FALSE) { } else { 
        $desc9x4 = "-" . " " . $model['viewfinder'] . " " . "Viewfinder" . " ";
    }


} elseif ($model['interchangeable'] == 0) { 

    if (strpos($model['zoom'], "-") !== FALSE) { } else { 
        $desc9x1 = "-" . " " . $model['zoom'] . " " . "Zoom" . " ";
    }
    if (strpos($model['macro_focus'], "-") !== FALSE) { } else { 
        $desc9x2 = "-" . " " . $model['macro_focus'] . " " . "Macro Focus" . " ";
    }
    if (strpos($model['wide_angle'], "-") !== FALSE) { } else { 
        $desc9x3 = "-" . " " . $model['wide_angle'] . " " . "wide-angle lens" . " ";
    }


}
if (strpos($model['screen_size'], "-") !== FALSE) { } else { 

    $desc9 = "and a" . " " . $model['screen_size'] . " " . "inch screen.";

}
```

Comment: I don't know exactly what you want. But it sounds like you should have a Look at switch()!

Comment: I'd put them into an array and use `array_filter` to remove the empty ones.

Comment: @iainn  This is a good idea, I know how to use array filter to check if the variable inside array contains a string, how would you check if variable inside array is 'isset'

Answer (score 0):

When you use a ternary operator like this, you shouldn't echo inline, but instead print the resulting variable, `$description`. Then you'll need to group the conditions with parenthesis, otherwise you might no get expected results.

```
echo $description = (isset($desc1) ? $desc1 : '') . (isset($desc2) ? $desc2 : '');
```

Alternatively, you can avoid grouping them if you use a comma instead of a period when concatenating the strings together.

```
echo $description = isset($desc1) ? $desc1 : '', isset($desc2) ? $desc2 : '';
```

- [Live demo](https://3v4l.org/fcuiA)

If you have more than 20 variables, it sounds easier to store them all in an array, and filter them as needed, then use that array to print what you need. If you show some expanded structure of your code, I can edit my answer to show a solution for that too.

Comment: Thankyou for your reply, I believe an array filter is the way to go here, how could I check if isset inside an array filter ?

Comment: That would be appreciated if you could show the array filter method, thank you very much

Comment: Can you show how you define those variables (`$desc1`, `$desc2`) to begin with?

Comment: Here is how I set $desc2 : $desc2 = "interchangeable lens" . " " . substr($category_name['category'], 0, -1) . " ";

Comment: Here Is how $desc1 is set : $desc1 = "Released " . $model['month'] . " " . $model['year'] . "," . " ". "the" . " " . $brand['brand'] . " " . $model['model'] . " " . "is an";

Comment: But is it conditionally set, is that why you're using `isset($desc2)` to begin with?

Comment: I will edit my question above and add the whole chunk of variables I am setting, yes they are conditionally set, thanks again

Comment: I just added how I set my variables in my question, thank you

Comment: Seeing your edit, why do you define them as individual variables at all? Do you need to use them separately at some point?